# Summarizing the count of values of one column in 2 different columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a df  called `reviews_gh` with the following format

```
Date         Market  Positive.or.Negative.
01-01-2020     A              Positive
01-01-2020     A              Positive
01-01-2020     B              Positive
01-01-2020     B              Negative
....
```

I am trying to group by date and business and create a new column called positive and negative that sums the number of times a negative and a positive are in that Market on that day

this is the code I have right now

```
  reviews_gh_agg <- reviews_gh %>% 
  group_by(Date, Market) %>% 
  summarise(positive = sum(reviews_gh$Positive.or.Negative.=="Positive"), negative = 
  sum(reviews_gh$Positive.or.Negative.=="Negative") )
```

But the result I get is wrong, I am getting on the new positive and negative column the TOTAL sum of ALL the observations, not grouped by day and market

the result for the small example at top should be

```
    Date         Market  Positive     Negative
01-01-2020     A            2            0
01-01-2020     B            1            1
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this is what you are looking for. I just made a slight modification to your code as you don't need `$` to refer to a column name in `tidyverse` thanks to data masking.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Date, Market) %>% 
  summarise(positive = sum(Positive.or.Negative.=="Positive"), negative = 
              sum(Positive.or.Negative.=="Negative"))


# A tibble: 2 x 4
# Groups:   Date [1]
  Date       Market positive negative
  <chr>      <chr>     <int>    <int>
1 01-01-2020 A             2        0
2 01-01-2020 B             1        1
```

**Updated**
Yet another valuable solution by dear @akrun.

```
df %>%
  group_by(Date, Market) %>%
  summarise(out = list(table(Positive.or.Negative.)), .groups = "drop") %>%
  unnest_wider(c(out))

# A tibble: 2 x 4
  Date       Market Positive Negative
  <chr>      <chr>     <int>    <int>
1 01-01-2020 A             2       NA
2 01-01-2020 B             1        1
```

**Date**

```
df <- tribble(
  ~Date,         ~Market,  ~Positive.or.Negative.,
  "01-01-2020",     "A",              "Positive",
  "01-01-2020",     "A",              "Positive",
  "01-01-2020",     "B",              "Positive",
  "01-01-2020",     "B",              "Negative"
)
```

Comment: Or another option with `table` `df %>% group_by(Date, Market) %>% summarise(out = list(table(Positive.or.Negative.)), .groups = 'drop') %>% unnest_wider(c(out))`

Comment: Thank you dear @akrun, I have never used `table` in a call to `summarize` but it seems like an interesting idea as we are looking for the contingency table of counts here. The code above does not belong to me as I thought the solution is already there and just needed a little tweaks so all the credits goes to the OP. I will add you solution to my post in your name. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another `tidyverse` solution, using `count` and `pivot_wider`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  # Group by Date, Market and Positive/Negative
  group_by(Date, Market, Positive.or.Negative.) %>%
  # Count
  count() %>%
  # Change to wide format, fill NA with 0's
  pivot_wider(names_from = Positive.or.Negative.,
              values_from = n,
              values_fill = 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `tidyr::pivot_wider` :

```
tidyr::pivot_wider(df, names_from = Positive.or.Negative., 
                       values_from = Positive.or.Negative., 
                       values_fn = length, 
                       values_fill = 0)

#  Date       Market Positive Negative
#  <chr>      <chr>     <int>    <int>
#1 01-01-2020 A             2        0
#2 01-01-2020 B             1        1
```

and with `data.table` :

```
library(data.table)

dcast(setDT(df),  Date + Market~Positive.or.Negative., 
      value.var = 'Positive.or.Negative.', fun.aggregate = length)
```